# Xamarin Forms - InitializeComponent exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm getting an exception on a Xamarin Forms content page with Xaml, on the initializecomponent method.  The exception occurs on the generated xaml.gs page.  I haven't changed any code form a working version.  Maybe something upstream has changed.   The exception message is ""

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: binding

stack trace:
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetBinding (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty targetProperty, Xamarin.Forms.BindingBase binding, System.Boolean fromStyle) [0x00011] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:293 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetBinding (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty targetProperty, Xamarin.Forms.BindingBase binding) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:117 
  at ....LoginPage.InitializeComponent () [0x00045] in ...\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\Views\Navigation\Login.xaml.g.cs:34 
  at FieldServices.LoginPage..ctor () [0x0002b] in ..\Views\Navigation\Login.xaml.cs:25

where occurrs:

[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "0.0.0.0")]
        private void InitializeComponent() {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(LoginPage));
            email = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName(this, "email");
            password = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName(this, "password");
            loginButton = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName(this, "loginButton");
        }

Comment: I should add the xaml previews fine in a xaml previewer, so I'm doubting its a xaml error

Comment: It seems there's something wrong with your binding part. Can you offer some code to specify more? Moreover, can you reproduce it on a new blank project?

Comment: This only occurs on this project.  Its happening on any xaml page so I'm not sure what is being bound and where.  Some xaml pages have no binding

Answer (score 0):

I rarely get this error when pulling code down. First, double-check that your code is fine. In this case, I would make sure all the bindings are named correctly with no typos.

In the event that you cannot find an error and are thoroughly convinced there is nothing wrong with the code, try steps like

- Clean and Rebuild
- Close your Visual Studio and restart it

Hopefully the error is solved as easy as this.

Answer (score 0):

On top of cleaning and rebuilding, manually delete all the obj and bin folders from your solution directory. Those xaml.gs files are generated files and sometimes they seem to not regenerate when they should.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting an exception on a Xamarin Forms content page with Xaml, on the initializecomponent method. The exception occurs on the generated xaml.gs page. I haven't changed any code form a working version. Maybe something upstream has changed.

It is not reproduceable by myside, but per experience there are a few things you can try:

1. Put your project in a short path like "C:\".
2. Try a new blank project, see if the error occors.
3. If none of the above works, you can try reinstalling Xamarin in your VS.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved due to my not linking a static resource that was declared in the xaml